# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot open database "aspnet-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm getting this error. I don't have this aspnet-xxx database.
my connectionstring:

```
"Connection": "server=LIMBUWAN\\SANJOKSQL;database=TravelMateDB;Trusted_Connection=true;"
```

I've also given my user Login "Login failed for user 'LIMBUWAN\sanli'.'" dbowner permission in SSMS.
[image: Code Throwing Error]
From Output:

at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:adda3d11-f81a-42cc-bacb-baf34690c993
Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
An exception of type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll but was not handled in user code
Cannot open database "aspnet-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'LIMBUWAN\sanli'.

Code Throwing Error.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;
        public List<SelectListItem> Country { get; set; }
        public IndexModel(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Country = GetCountry();
        }
        public List<SelectListItem> GetCountry()
        {
            var Country = _context.CoronaListCountries.ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> _Country = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var country in Country)
            {
                _Country.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = country.Id.ToString(), Text = country.Country });
            }
            return _Country;
        }
        public JsonResult OnGetGlobalChartData()
        {
            var globalData = _context.GlobalContexts.ToList();
            return new JsonResult(globalData);
        }
        public JsonResult OnGetSearch(int id)
        {
            var selectedCountry = _context.CoronaListCountries.Where(S => S.Id == id).ToList();
            return new JsonResult(selectedCountry);
        }
    }
}
```

My context Code

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<CoronaListCountryContext> CoronaListCountries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GlobalCasesContext> GlobalContexts { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<CoronaListCountryContext>().HasIndex(U => U.Country).IsUnique();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the actual code that throws. Are you sure you're using *that* connection string and not some other, hard-coded one? Have you configured a test connection perhaps? Post the *full* exception text too, not just the first part of the message

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos I've added an image and output. I hope this is sufficient. I only have one connection string.

Comment: Post the *code*, not an image of the code. Images can't be copied, compiled or googled. Since you use EF Core you need to post the context's configuration too, specifically the part where you configure the connection. One way or another you end up with the wrong connection string.

Comment: Were you using a User Instance database at some point, ie were you using `AttachDbFileName` in the connection string? Your application may be loading this connection string somehow. Perhaps you've copied the wrong settings file

Comment: No, I was not using such user Instance at any point.

Comment: Are you *sure*? You haven't posted the code that actually configures the connection string and registers the DbContext - the AddDbContext call in `Startup..cs`. Where does it load the connection string from? Put a breakpoint there and check what the *real* connection string is. If you used a one-liner to configure, ie `.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("..."))` extract the connection string into a variable and inspect it. It's not what you think it is

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos for pointing out where should I look into. I've solved this.

Comment: I just had this problem. Have you deployed to Azure? Seems like deploying my project somehow resulted in a new localdb that my local project would point to, although it sounds unlikely.... After deleting the "aspnet-21838721..." local database and re-deploying my project to Azure, the problem went away. Whether this is the actual way to solve it, or something else happened in between, I cant say.

Comment: @thesystem Yes I did. I think the problem then for me was incorrect DB configuration while publishing. I think I resolved it by using the correct DB in publish windows options. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @ShanksLimbu Thanks for the answer. Yes that sounds likely to be a problem with incorrect setup while publishing to Azure. I am not sure what "publish windows options" is though?

Answer (score 1):

If the trusted connection fails. Try with the standard where you provide user and password

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: The standard way is to use a Windows account, not SQL Logins. Changing the authentication type won't fix an attempt to connect to the wrong database either

Comment: That connection string can be used only for SQL Logins, not Windows accounts. In this case the connection is made to a local server using a local account, so Windows authentication will work as long as the database is correct and the user has permissions